# VBA to search for values and change format for Row + 2

Tags: vba, excel, range

Can someone give me a helping hand with the following piece of vba? What I am trying to achieve is search for a string of text in a column and if it matches my criteria, change the format of a dynamic range. I am having a hard time figuring out how to make that range dynamic. It's always the rows that are matching the string + 2.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub FormatPercentages()
Dim RowToTest As Long


For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.count, 27).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 27)
    If .Value Like "*Efficiency*" _
    Then _
    Range("AD129:AS131").NumberFormat = "0%"
End With

Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

I need help on the range part:**Range("AD129:AS131").NumberFormat = "0%"**
I think it should be something like this although I am aware that it's poorly written (*AD & "N" : &  AD.xlToRight & "N"+2*). Where N is the row number that matches the string Efficiency.

Thank you,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the confusion comes from the strange usage of `_`. Does it work like this?

```
Sub FormatPercentages()

    Dim RowToTest As Long

    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, 27)
            If .Value Like "*Efficiency*" Then
                Range("AD" & RowToTest & ":AD" & RowToTest + 2).NumberFormat = "0%"
            End If
        End With
    Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

I have not tested it, but it looks like what you need, assuming that `N` from your question is `RowToTest`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You were blazing fast too! Thank you so much Vityata!

Answer (score 3):

Try the `Resize` property:

```
Range("AD" & RowToTest).Resize(3, 1).NumberFormat = "0%"
```

Or,

```
Cells(RowToTest, 27).Resize(3, 1).NumberFormat = "0%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Either go with your code like this:

```
...
If .Value Like "*Efficiency*" Then
    Range(Cells(RowToTest, 27), Cells(RowToTest, 27).End(xlToRight)).NumberFormat = "0%"
End If
...
```

or if starting at row 3 use conditional formatting (you do start at 2... sadly)

```
Range:   =$AD$3:$BD$10000
Formula: =OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Efficiency",$D1:$D3)))
```

conditional formatting also goes back of no "Efficiency" is found... (replace `SEARCH` with `FIND` if you want to search with case sensitive)